# SharePoint connector missing in LogiApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps

I am not able to see the SharePoint connector in Logic Apps to trigger. Can you please help me  as I am stuck.

[image]
Trying to connect Logic Apps to Sharepoint list to trigger when an item is added or modified to list but I cannot see the Sharepoint connector itself.

Comment: You’re using standard, do you need to? Consumption has it.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Skin, sharepoint connector is available in Consumption Plan but if you are required to use standard plan make sure while searching you navigate to `Azure` tab where you can find the missing connector.

[image]